# How do I add a image overlay through css?

Tags: html, css, hover, overlay

I need an image overlay for the html I have set up. Below is my code for the "change a profile photo" upload area.

-icon_camera_128.png is the image that needs to be the hover effect.

-img class="cameraUpoad is the default profile photo.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks

```
<label for="fileUploadLink" class="custom-file-upload">
 <div class="changeProfile">
  <img src="../img/elements/icon_camera_128.png">
   <img class="cameraUpload" style="width: 128px; height: 128px;" src="data:image/png;base64, <?= preg_replace("/\"/", "\\\"", base64_encode($user['avatar'])) ?>" alt="avatar">
    <input id="fileUploadLink" type="file" class="filestyle" name="imageUpload" />
```

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "image overlay"? Do you need a hover efect?

Comment: correct, I need a hover effect. Sorry! Long day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give a wrap of the images a `position: relative;` and and the two images  (regular state and hovered state) `position: absolute;` while adjusting `opacity` of the hovered image:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6kkwspd6/1/)

Something like:

```
.changeProfile {
    position: relative;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
.cameraUpload {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .4s;
    z-index: 999;
}
.cameraUpload:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```